# Encountered an error during installing android studio in debian

Tags: android-studio, debian

bin$ ./studio.sh
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
downloaded the android studio and extract to a folder.then open it with terminal then a i entered $./studio.sh

resulted to this command i got above mentioned code .What does it mean and how can i solve it?

how can i download Android Studio.please explain what i need to do next.